# Difference between Sqlcmd and Invoke-Sqlcmd

Tags: powershell, t-sql, database-administration, sqlcmd

I am trying to learn Sqlcmd utility in PowerShell to run SQL queries, specifically for database administration.

Using `Version 15.0.1300.359 NT`

But I got confused, what is the difference between `Sqlcmd` and `Invoke-Sqlcmd`?

Why is it this command works:

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance myinstance -Database AdventureWorks2017 "select top 3 * from [Person].[BusinessEntity]"
```

And this one does not work:

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -S myinstance -d AdventureWorks2017 "select top 3 * from [Person].[BusinessEntity]"
```

By querying help I can clearly see that I should be able using all those variables:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

- [`Invoke-SqlCmd`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/invoke-sqlcmd?view=sqlserver-ps) is one of the PowerShell cmdlets from the [`SqlServer` Module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/?view=sqlserver-ps)
- `sqlcmd` is a [Microsoft Utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility?view=sql-server-ver15)

If you're working on PowerShell scripting, I would recommend the use of the Module whenever possible. `Invoke-SqlCmd` will output objects, which are definitely easier to manipulate.